# Create table with description properties access to song list

Tags: mysql, sql, diagram

There are 3 tables User and SongList (one-to-many), 1 user can have 1 and more songList. SubList (one-to-many) to SongList. SongList can be public (visible for all), private (only owner can view) and friendly (owner + some other user(s)). Maybe for SubList same (private, public ...) should be, nevertheless it's not important now.

How better to do that?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`user` (
  `username` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `password` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`song_list` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `cretaed` DATE NOT NULL,
  `updated` DATE NULL,
  `user_id` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `fk_group_user1_idx` (`user_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_group_user1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`user` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`subgroup` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  `created` DATE NULL,
  `updated` DATE NULL,
  `song_list_id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `song_list_id`),
  INDEX `fk_subgroup_song_list1_idx` (`song_list_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_subgroup_song_list1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`song_list_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`song_list` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

Thank you.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

Just model it directly. Add another table e.g.
`AccessType (AccessTypeID int, AccessTypeName varchar(200))`
Insert here records e.g. 1-public, 2-private, etc. Then in your tables
SongList and SubSongList add AccessTypeID columns and
make them foreign keys (FKs) pointing to the AccessType table.
Tables like AccessType are usually called lookup tables.